# SQL Cursor to Insert into Temporary Table and Fetch From Temparory Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

Sir,

I have build a SQL query using Cursor as @AllRecords to insert values into Temporary Table & then Fetch values from that temporary table. But it showing me an error at last statement when I am fetching values from table (Error: incorrect syntax near @AllRecords). Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(20)=null,
        @Query varchar(MAX)=null,
        @DepartmentName varchar(50)=null,
        @deptt_code varchar(4)=null,
        @DistrictId varchar(4)='0001',
        @Deptt_Id char(4)=null,
        @stYear varchar(4)=null, 
        @cYear varchar(4)=null,
        @yr varchar(9)='2017-2018',
        @tno int

BEGIN
        set @stYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,0,5)
        set @cYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,6,4)

--DECLARE & SET COUNTER
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 1

--CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE WITH COLs
DECLARE @AllRecords table
(
  department_name varchar(50),
  project_name varchar(100),
  department_code varchar(4)
 )

--*** Declare Cursor
DECLARE cur_FetchDepartmentName CURSOR READ_ONLY
 FOR 
  select deptt_code,deptt_name+'('+ RTRIM(LTRIM(deptt_short))+')' as dept_name from m_Department 
  where deptt_code in (select distinct department_code from t_Project_Details where district_id=@DistrictId
  and financial_year=@yr)

OPEN cur_FetchDepartmetName

fetch next from cur_FetchDepartmetName into 
@deptt_code, @DepartmentName

--LOOP UNTIL RECORDS ARE AVAILABLE
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
   BEGIN
      if(@tno=0)
          BEGIN
                set @tno=1
                insert into @AllRecords values(@DepartmentName,@deptt_code)
                fetch next from cur_FetchDepartmetName into
                @deptt_code,@DepartmentName
          END
      else
          BEGIN
                set @tno=@tno+1
                insert into @AllRecords values(@DepartmentName,@deptt_code)
                fetch next from cur_FetchDepartmetName into
                @deptt_code,@DepartmentName
          END

   END
        --CLOSE CURSOR
        CLOSE cur_FetchDepartmetName
        DEALLOCATE cur_FetchDepartmetName

  select department_name, department_code from @AllRecords
```

Comment: Where you set your first variables, you have `BEGIN` which doesn't have an associated `END`

Comment: This has to be the best example ever of unnecessary use of cursors. Please, stop, take a breath, and rewrite this as a simple INSERT..SELECT statement. I would say to use ROW_NUMBER() or IDENTITY() to get @tNo, but I see no point, you don't use them any further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of answering what is error in this solution, I would like to offer a better solution to the problem. Use of cursor in this example is completely unnecessary, query can be more easily be written without it. It's a simple INSERT..SELECT statement and counting of records to set @tno can easily be done in the end.

```
BEGIN

set @stYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,0,5);
set @cYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,6,4);

--CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE WITH COLs
DECLARE @AllRecords table
(
  department_name varchar(50),
  project_name varchar(100), --what's the use of this column?
  department_code varchar(4)
 );

INSERT INTO @AllRecords (department_code, department_name)
select deptt_code,deptt_name+'('+ RTRIM(LTRIM(deptt_short))+')' as dept_name from m_Department 
  where deptt_code in (select distinct department_code from t_Project_Details where district_id=@DistrictId
  and financial_year=@yr);


SELECT @tNo = COALESCE(@tno,0) + COUNT(*) FROM @AllRecords;

select department_name, department_code from @AllRecords;

END
```

Please check this article about cursors and how to avoid them:

[Cursors and How to Avoid Them](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them)

Comment: Sir, `project_name varchar(100)` this column is for another Project Table which has project details and also uploaded under corresponding Department.

Comment: Sir actually I have to fetch each department and also to fetch the Projects correspond to that department from Projects Table

Comment: @SumeetKumar Whatever the problem is, cursors are probably not needed

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query as below :

```
  BEGIN
         DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(20)= NULL, @Query VARCHAR(MAX)= NULL, @DepartmentName VARCHAR(50)= NULL, @deptt_code VARCHAR(4)= NULL, @DistrictId VARCHAR(4)= '0001', @Deptt_Id CHAR(4)= NULL, @stYear VARCHAR(4)= NULL, @cYear VARCHAR(4)= NULL, @yr VARCHAR(9)= '2017-2018', @tno INT;
         SET @stYear = SUBSTRING(@yr, 0, 5);
         SET @cYear = SUBSTRING(@yr, 6, 4);

--DECLARE & SET COUNTER
         DECLARE @counter INT;
         SET @counter = 1;

--CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE WITH COLs
         DECLARE @AllRecords TABLE
         (department_name VARCHAR(50),
          project_name    VARCHAR(100),
          department_code VARCHAR(4)
         );

--*** Declare Cursor
         DECLARE cur_FetchDepartmentName CURSOR READ_ONLY
         FOR
             SELECT deptt_code,
                    deptt_name+'('+RTRIM(LTRIM(deptt_short))+')' AS dept_name
             FROM m_Department
             WHERE deptt_code IN
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                        department_code
                 FROM t_Project_Details
                 WHERE district_id = @DistrictId
                       AND financial_year = @yr
             );
         OPEN cur_FetchDepartmetName;
         FETCH NEXT FROM cur_FetchDepartmetName INTO @deptt_code, @DepartmentName;

--LOOP UNTIL RECORDS ARE AVAILABLE
         WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
             BEGIN
                 IF(@tno = 0)
                     BEGIN
                         SET @tno = 1;
                         INSERT INTO @AllRecords
                         (department_name,
                          department_code
                         )
                                SELECT @DepartmentName,
                                       @deptt_code;
                         FETCH NEXT FROM cur_FetchDepartmetName INTO @deptt_code, @DepartmentName;
                 END;
                     ELSE
                     BEGIN
                         SET @tno = @tno + 1;
                         INSERT INTO @AllRecords
                         (department_name,
                          department_code
                         )
                                SELECT @DepartmentName,
                                       @deptt_code;
                         FETCH NEXT FROM cur_FetchDepartmetName INTO @deptt_code, @DepartmentName;
                 END;
             END;
        --CLOSE CURSOR
         CLOSE cur_FetchDepartmetName;
         DEALLOCATE cur_FetchDepartmetName;

        select department_name, department_code from @AllRecords
     END;
```